# Transpose 2 Columns into 1 Row, Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-finance

The Google Sheets formula below is located in column A1 of my Google Sheet. This formula creates data in column A & B. I need to transpose this data into 1 row

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(A2,"price",TODAY()-30,TODAY())

=TRANSPOSE(GOOGLEFINANCE(A2,"price",TODAY()-30,TODAY()))
```

The transpose formula successfully transposes the data in the 2 columns to 2 rows, as it should. My question is, will there be a way to transpose two columns of data into 1 single row - I have searched around for a solution for Google Sheets without any Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use famous "double query smush" like:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(GOOGLEFINANCE(A2, "price", TODAY()-30, TODAY())),,999^99)),,999^99)
```

Comment: great, any way to strip out the data of say column B and just transpose column a ?

Comment: sure: `=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(A2, "price", TODAY()-30, TODAY()), "select Col1", 0)),,999^99)),,999^99)`

Comment: this worked like a charm, thank you very much - last thing though, it is putting all of the data into one cell.... is there a way the formula can put each piece of transposed data into its own cell?

Comment: try: `=SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(A2, "price", TODAY()-30, TODAY()), "select Col1", 0)),,999^99)),,999^99), " ")`

Comment: seriously amazing stuff, thanks again for your help this answered my question exactly! :)